# Yii2- Unable to pass multiple parameters while submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, form-submit

I am working on `Yii2`. I have two buttons and I m submitting it via Javascript `onClick` function also I am trying to pass multiple parameters like `id`, `name` etc but it's not allowing me to do it.

```
 <a class="<?= $model->isNewRecord ?>" onclick="
      $('#simmapping-form').submit();" href="javascript:;">
        <?= $model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update' , ['id'=> 'spin','name'=>'create','class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-success'] ?></a>
```

The error I am getting is

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Array to string conversion at line 55

and the line 55 is

```
<?= $model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update' , ['id'=> 'spin','name'=>'create','class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-success'] ?>
```

I am also familiar with `Html::submitButton()` but I don't want to use it.

How can I add multiple parameters while submitting a form?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your issue is that your line 55. isn't formatted well, what are you trying to achieve with this exactly?
Replace the 55 line with `<?= $model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update' ?>` and just add simple HTML id, name and class attributes.

Comment: @demi like this ? `<a class="<?= $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-success' ?>" id="spin" name="create" onclick="$('#sim-form').submit();" href="javascript:;">
            <?= $model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update' ?></a>`

Comment: Yes, but also you should consider having a seperate JS file where you would listen to the link click event and then executing a function.
Considering that you use a link for submitting a form, I'd also suggest you use a button, and then if you have to manipulate the submitted form data, just make a form submit listener.

Comment: tried this way but I have an issue with my controller. I am checking the name of the button with `if(isset($_POST['create']))` but it's not entering in the if condition

Comment: I would highly recommend you look more into PHP forms (without considering any PHP frameworks). You cannot retrieve data like this, links can't be passed/submitted.

Try using hidden input fields to pass data: [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden)

Does this help?

Comment: @demi I have already done this while using `<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['id'=> 'ror','name'=>'done','class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-success']) ?>` but in this case I want to use form subimtting

Comment: what do you actually want why are you using an anchor for submitting the form, and then at the same time want to check `$_POST['create']` to after submitting? why don't you use a submit button instead?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam bro There are two submit buttons `Create` and `OEM Return` and against them, I am using a single controller. I have already used `Html::submitButton()` and it's working. But while  using a scanner input the forms tries to refresh and I don't want to do it. So that's why I am using `submit form`. Also I have used the same in other views but with no extra parameters passing

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="<?= ($model->isNewRecord) ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary' ?>" onclick="$('#simmapping-form').submit();" href="javascript:;" id="spin" name="create">
    <?= $model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update' ?>
</a>
```

Using Yii2 Html helper :

```
<?= Html::a(
    $model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update',
    'javascript:;',
    [
        'class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary',
        'onclick' => '$("#simmapping-form").submit();',
        'id' => 'spin',
        'name' => 'create',
    ]
) ?>
```

Comment: Why would you create an extra variable `class` and why do you have quote marks on _id_ and _name_ attributes?
Also check the comments first, OP posted the same (if not better) snippet)

Comment: @demi class attribute is not extra its for css to change the button design. I cannot find OP comment but he can answer even if there is another answer because of that there is vote up and down.

Comment: Didn't mean the attribute, but a variable, which was edited/removed by comment writer.